# Check if form date is older than 4 months

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with a date picker, which checks if the selected date is not older than 4 months. But my script doesn't work now, because of a new year (2018).

```
if ((today.getMonth() + 11) - (date.getMonth() + 11) > 4) {
    console.log("test");
}
```

It doesn't check for the months of 2017. I can't find a solution to fix this, does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: your if conditions are kind of redundant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 if(today - date > 1000/*ms*/ * 60/*s*/ * 60/*min*/ * 24/*h*/ * 30/*days*/ * 3/*months*/)
   alert("to old!");
```

Alternatively:

```
 const fourMonthsAgo = new Date();
 fourMonthsAgo.setMonth(fourMonthsAgo.getMonth() - 4);

 if(+fourMonthsAgo > +date)
  alert("to old");
```

Comment: and thats how you do it :D

Comment: which one is better? I think the second one? and why do you use '+' on fourMonthsAgo and date by the if statement? @orangespark

Comment: + is used to convert string to digit

Comment: @can and its more precise (as the first ond assumes that a month has 30 days and the second also considers leap seconds etc.)

Comment: Is the + needed? Date comparisons work on their own don't they?

Comment: @Programmingjoe yes, comparing two non numbers with > calls `.valueOf` on them which is the same as explicitly calling `+`, however I like the explicitness here :)

Answer (score 1):

Just compare like this;

```
  var diff =(today.getTime() - date.getTime()) / 1000;
  diff = diff / (60 * 60 * 24 * 10 * 3);
  var diffMonths = Math.abs(Math.round(diff));
  if(diffMonths > 4)
  {
    var $errordate = $( "<div id='error-field' class='error-field'><p>Error text</p></div>" );
    $("#divContainer").append($errordate);
    $('#nextButton').prop('disabled', true);
  }
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3n2obgv7/3/)